# Stenographic projection of $S^{2}$ sphere.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In my notes:
[image]

the there exists a line $\imath \left ( p \right )$ that intersects any fixed coordinate N and any point p in $S^{2}$.

Consider a point $p_{1}$ in the region z>0.
Indeed, the line $\imath \left ( p_{1} \right )$ intersects $p_{1}$ and N and cuts plane z=0 at some point $q_{1}$ on the plane z=0. However, I fail to understand why for any point p in the region $z>0$, the map of the point p is to the region outside of $S^{2}$.

Any clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: Although your title is a mis-spelling, I am loath to correct it, because I like the idea of a "stenographic projection" with its mid-twentieth century implications.

Comment: @LeeMosher You have to forgive me. Its been slightly more than 24 hrs since I had a wink and there's a paper awaiting me in less than 12 hours.

Comment: Not at all! As I said, I like your mis-spelling :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting "stereographic projection" into an image search? When I did with Google, this was the second result:

[image: sterographicprojection]

(Unfortunately reverse image search was not able to give me the original source of the image.)

Indeed, if you solve for the point $q$ to get an algebraic expression for it as a function of $p$, you should be able to justify formally why this occurs.

Comment: I haven't but I tried Wolfram and Wikipedia. So the failing point for me seems to be that I failed to consider the plane z=0 as an 'infinite' plane.